# Mail server with smart-host

Tags: email, dns, postfix-mta, smarthost

I want to create a mail server, but my ISP does not allow reverse-IP record, so I ordered a VPS with such function. But I want use VPS only as a relaying server and my own server as an actual mail server (so it should have things like web-mail, and some other). I did not find any guides, but looks like VPS will be called a "smart-host". So I installed Axigen on my server, but it requires login and password for connecting to a smart-host. I tried to use postfix for relaying but I did non figure out how to properly configure it. What are my options?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To securely enable postfix as a mail forwarding server, you'll have to enable and configure SASL authentication.  The postfix [SASL README](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) has all the details.  I suggest dovecot as the backend, as it's the simplest to setup.  After that, just create a new system user (`adduser mail-forwarding`) and configure Axigen to use that user for forwarding.

If I understand correctly, your goal is to forward outgoing mail from your local server to the VPS while incoming mail should be stored on the local server.  This is possible, but not necessarily simple.  Mail needs to be handled differently depending on how it reaches your local server, otherwise you might end up with a mail loop, with your servers playing pingping using  mail sent back and forth.